# IM Service By XMPP

Tags: java, xmpp, chat

I want to create a IM service, that use XMPP. I don't want to use GTalk, Facebook Chat and ... services. How can I get start? Actually I want to create a app that has all popular services like text chat, voice chat, video chat, group chat and ... How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can start by using XMPP server like OpenFire - which comes with server implementation, thick client, borwser based flash client and javascript client.

Such solutions provide you all the functionality as platform and you can setup you solution very easily.

You can visit official site of openfire for more information: http://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/openfire/

Comment: Actually I want to create a app for all platform (android, iOS X, Windows, Linux). Please Explain More. Thanks for your answer :D

Comment: OpenFire is distributed application - you can run the server on one of the supported platform. Chat client can be built on the platforms you have mentioned - infact OpenFire provides clients for most of the platforms you have mentioned. Please refer the link http://www.igniterealtime.org/downloads/index.jsp for details of components available with OpenFire